# echoing javascript with php including mysql row variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to echo javascript code using php and trying to retrieve data from my database within this very echo-code... Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Is it because javascript is only client-side? (Technically, I'm trying to reach the database with php...) I would appreciate some help!

```
<?php
if($condition == true){

//connect to the database
//-select the database to use
//-query the database table
//-run the query against the mysql query function
//-create while loop and loop through result set 



echo    "<script>  
    items_set = [
        {
         src : '<?php echo ".$row['imageURL']." ?>', 
         url : '<?php echo ".$row['URL']." ?>', 
         category: '<?php echo ".$row['DetailCategory']." ?>', 
         title : '<?php echo ".$row['Name']." ?>', 
         description : '<?php echo ".$row['Description']." ?>', 
         price : '<?php echo ".$row['Price']." ?>', 
         location : '<?php echo ".$row['Postcode']." ?>', 
         thirdparty : '<?php echo ".$row['ThirdParty']." ?>', 
         thirdparty_mobile : '<?php echo ".$row['Thirdparty']." ?>'
        }           
    ];
    jQuery('#list').portfolio_addon({
        load_count : 1,
        items : items_set
    }); 
</script>";


}}

?>
```

Thanks in advance!
(In Dreamweaver the colors of the code look right, unlike here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you separate what gets executed in your server (PHP) and what is passed to the client and executed in the browser:

```
<?php if(condition == true){ ?>
<script>
    items_set = [
        {src : "<?php echo $row['imageURL']; ?>", 
            url : "<?php echo $row['URL']; ?>", 
            category: "<?php echo $row['DetailCategory']; ?>",
            title : "<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>",
            description : "<?php echo $row['Description']; ?>", 
            price : "<?php echo $row['Price']; ?>",
            location : "<?php echo $row['Postcode']; ?>", 
            thirdparty : "<?php echo $row['ThirdParty']; ?>",
            thirdparty_mobile : "<?php echo $row['Thirdparty']; ?>"}         
    ];
    jQuery('#list').portfolio_addon({
        load_count : 1,
        items : items_set
    }); 
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Notice I modified your code to make strings variables, given that the `$row` variable is part of your PHP code, not your JavaScript.

Comment: The code formating is a good practice. I think he has mistaken because his code was not well formated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now everything works as it should! @bksi: you might be right, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

in your php:

```
//specify header..

header("content-type:application/json");

//create variables for your values

 $row['values'];

//create oo array
arrayResult = 
  array(
 array("variable-name" => $variable,"imageURL" => $imageURL)
      );
```

In your html..

```
    //get data using JSON
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $j.getJSON( "cellJson.php", function( json ) {
        $j.each(json, function(i, item) {
    //example
    var imageURL = item.imageURL;

    //then in your script

      items_set = [
            {
src : ''+imageURL+'', 
url : ''+URL+'', 
category: ''+DetailCategory+'', 
title : ''+Name+''
            }         
        ];
        jQuery('#list').portfolio_addon({
            load_count : 1,
            items : items_set
        });

    });

    </script>
```